# Remember the values entered on standalone app on the client side

Tags: java, swing

We have a standalone java swing app, in which the user can print something that he drew, on a printer by giving its IP.

Now the requirement is that the app needs to remember the ip that was given the last time by this user.

What I could think of till now is (a brute one though) - keep a log file kind of storage on the client machine, and that everytime the app comes up it reads the last submitted one.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a tutorial on using the Java [Preferences](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPreferences/article.html) API to achieve what you want.
From the article:

> The Java Preferences API provides a
>   systematic way to handle user and
>   system preference and configuration
>   data, e.g. to save user settings,
>   remember the last value of a field
>   etc.

I would use this approach over writing any data out explicitly to a file because its platform agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

More or Less that's it. Still you can review the source code for **[HistoryTextField](http://www.jedit.org/api/org/gjt/sp/jedit/gui/HistoryTextField.html)** component of [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/).
http://www.jedit.org/api/org/gjt/sp/jedit/gui/HistoryTextField.html

A Sample from jEdit source:

```
public boolean save(Map<String, HistoryModel> models)
{
    Log.log(Log.MESSAGE,HistoryModel.class,"Saving history");
    File file1 = new File(MiscUtilities.constructPath(
        jEdit.getSettingsDirectory(), "#history#save#"));
    File file2 = new File(MiscUtilities.constructPath(
        jEdit.getSettingsDirectory(), "history"));
    if(file2.exists() && file2.lastModified() != historyModTime)
    {
        Log.log(Log.WARNING,HistoryModel.class,file2
            + " changed on disk; will not save history");
        return false;
    }

    jEdit.backupSettingsFile(file2);

    String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    BufferedWriter out = null;

    try
    {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(file1), "UTF-8"));

        if(models != null)
        {
            Collection<HistoryModel> values = models.values();
            for (HistoryModel model : values)
            {
                if(model.getSize() == 0)
                    continue;

                out.write('[');
                out.write(StandardUtilities.charsToEscapes(
                    model.getName(),TO_ESCAPE));
                out.write(']');
                out.write(lineSep);

                for(int i = 0; i < model.getSize(); i++)
                {
                    out.write(StandardUtilities.charsToEscapes(
                        model.getItem(i),
                        TO_ESCAPE));
                    out.write(lineSep);
                }
            }
        }

        out.close();

        /* to avoid data loss, only do this if the above
         * completed successfully */
        file2.delete();
        file1.renameTo(file2);
    }
    catch(IOException io)
    {
        Log.log(Log.ERROR,HistoryModel.class,io);
    }
    finally
    {
        IOUtilities.closeQuietly(out);
    }

    historyModTime = file2.lastModified();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a Swing app., you might launch it using Java Web Start then persist the data using the PersistenceService. Here is a [demo. of the PersistenceService](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).

Answer (score 0):

i dont really recommend this, but you could use the registry also.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it. Can you please provide some pointers?

Comment: @kshtjsnghl the Java Preferences APi in Amir's answer uses the registry, and makes it relatively easy to do so.