# Reopen JTree after application restart and save its state

Tags: java, swing, persistence, jtree

How could I save the selected and opened nodes in JTree and reopen it after user restart my Application?

Comment: check whether this link is useful http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19857.html

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  Which part are you stuck with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remember the values entered on standalone app on the client side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661352/remember-the-values-entered-on-standalone-app-on-the-client-side) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8282048/418556) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7954183/418556)..

Comment: @Sajith can you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can store the expansion state of JTree and retain it later when required. Check this code example. http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19857.html